# Django patch save in unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

In my code I have the class players with an method add_player:

```
class Players:

    def __init__(self):
        self.players = Player.objects.all()
        self.active_player_index = 0

    def add_player(self, player):
        player.save()
```

In my test I tried to do this:

```
class PlayersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.players = Players()
        self.players.players = []

    def fake_add_player(self, player):
        self.players.players.append(player)

    @patch.object(myproject.entities.Players, 'add_player', fake_add_player)
    def test_add_players(self):
            self.players.add_player(Player('player', 'blue', True))
            self.assertEqual(len(self.players.players), 1)
```

When running this test I get the error`" AttributeError: <module 'riskgame.entities.Players' from '/entities/Players.py'> does not have the attribute 'add_player'`. What is wrong in this test? Are there better ways to make Django unittests?

Comment: Is this how you intended the code? Looks like you added a "simple" functiuon outside the `Players` class.

Comment: Yes the question is just a bit simplified but I hope the idea is clear

Comment: What I mean is, is `add_player` in the scope (more to the right) of the `class Player` definition. here it looks like you defined a function *outside* of the `Players` class.

Comment: Good point, improved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mock the module `Players`, not the class `Players`. Try this:

```
@patch.object(myproject.entities.Players.Players, 'add_player', fake_add_player)
```

---

Some unrelated, unsolicited advice:

- apparently, you have a file called `Players.py` containing a class `Player`. I would expect that class to live in the `entities` module (`myproject/entities.py` instead of `myproject/entities/Players.py`).
- your `fake_add_players` is broken. It should be:

  ```
  def fake_add_player(self, player):
      self.players.append(player)
  ```

  After patch Players, `self` refers to `Players`, not `PlayersTest`. You might want to move the function out of the class to avoid that confusion.
- I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but I have a hunch that your `Players` class could also be a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).